# How to set up Sql Server reporting services 2016 with Auth0

Tags: auth0, ssrs-2016

I am trying to set up my SQL Server Reporting Server 2016 to accept Auth0 authentication. I can not find any links with this information. Could anyone point me in the right direction for finding information on how this is done.

Comment: You might have to use active directory to manage the SSRS users and then hook that up to Auth0

Comment: I should of mentioned that the authentication and DB of user's etc is set up. I am supposed to configure SSRS 2016 to be able to accept the credentials. That is the part I am not sure about. Do I do something in the Configuration Manager or the rsreportserver.config file? Apologies for not being clear initially.

Comment: Any updates for this one. Two years and still no suggested solution. I'm facing the same problem now with SSRS 2005 <-> Auth0. If I find anything, will update this thread

Comment: @MoZaatar Sorry about the late reply. No I never did get any information and now I have left that job.